# Sitecore High Availability Architecture

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

Page 14 of the scaling guide states

> The following diagram illustrates the connections between the Web
>   instances and the Sitecore databases for a setup which contains
>   isolated instances within the CM and CD environments

Using this set up I want to have a load balancer in front of CD1 and CD2 lets call it Geo region 1 and another load balancer in front of CD3 and CD4 lets call it geo region 2. I also need to have a DNS resolver that will fail over to geo region 2 as needed (strictly a fail over). It will have to be manually reset back to geo region 1 once all of the issues have been resolved. I am worried about the situation when a user changes their password in the CD1-2 zone and how that information gets back to the CORE db located in the CM1-2 zone.

I was planning on having one publishing target and using SQL Merge Replication between the databases and GEO locations as outlined in the diagram mentioned on page 14 of the scaling guide. It seems this setup will solve all syncing DB issues.

Is this a reasonable/working architecture for a high availability setup?

[Scaling guide URL](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http://www.sitecore.net/~/media/Products/Product%2520Categories/Web%2520Content%2520Management/Content%2520Management/Multisite%2520Deployment/scaling_guide_sc6364usletter.ashx&ei=6qWBUt3iIc7wkQfM24HoDQ&usg=AFQjCNHSoStWqs3RBPau6X19pIGsNy8FKQ&bvm=bv.56146854,d.eW0) if needed.

Comment: See point 2 of section 3.2.2, I should also consider extracting the [security from Core to a separate database](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Scrapbook/How%20to%20extract%20the%20security%20from%20Core%20to%20a%20separate%20database%20in%20Sitecore%206.aspx)

Comment: Going on @jammykam 's comment - removing the Core database is not recommended from Sitecore's perspective (as also mentioned here: http://sdn.sitecore.net/developer/configuring%20production%20environments.aspx). If you do remove the Core database, your Lucene indexes could have issues if you index all fields.

Comment: @mluker you have none of your (past) questions accepted. Kindly accept the helpful answers. It is general practice on Stackoverflow to mark/accept the helpful answers. Reference [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See page 12 of the guide.  The answer depends on if you are using the default SQL membership provider or an external provider like Active Directory.  If you are using the default membership provider, then you will want to set up replication between your core databases in the CD and CM environments as well as security cache clearing.  If you are using an external provider, you can usually skip replication of the core databases and just set up the security cache clearing.